# Android NDK using both C and C++ files

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using the Android NDK to access a library which is already in use for a Palm Pilot program, but looking deeper into it, I found that there is a single .cpp file within the library.

Will the NDK compile the library correctly having both C and C++ files within it, or do I need to create two separate libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project with mixed c/c++ code.. 
What I know for now is that ..

1. C++ code should be in a .cpp file (except if you specify in the Android.mk file by stating something like cxx_extension=cc or equivalent)
2. c code should be in a .c file

if you are working with code which is explicitly c in a cpp file or viceversa than you're bound only to the normal dev rules like

> extern "C" {//your C headers and code in C++ file}

etc...